# how to get absolute value of interval in django F expression?

Tags: django

I'm trying to sort by date difference between now and recorded date of a model instance.

The following are my best bet so far, but 'abs' part doesn't work

```
Support.objects.all().annotate(
             datediff=Func(ExpressionWrapper(
                 F('end_at')-Now(),
                 output_field=DurationField()), function='ABS')
         ).order_by('datediff', 'id')
```

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function abs(interval) does not
>   exist

I also tried

```
Support.objects.all().annotate(
             datediff=ExpressionWrapper(
                 Func(F('end_at')-Now(), function='ABS'),
                 output_field=DurationField())
         ).order_by('datediff', 'id')
```

with the same error.

Comment: For sorting, in your case, it should produce the same order as if simply sorting by `end_at`. This would also be much faster than calculating the duration for all rows, then sort - and then just show the first n rows. Rather sort and show the first n rows and calculate the duration only for those (e.g. via templatetag).